# Is "delightfully shambolic" an oxymoron or not?

Tags: oxymoron

A friend has claimed the term "delightfully shambolic" is an oxymoron. I disagree as I don't see that they're contradictory as such, more just strange bedfellows. Surely something along the lines of "delightfully unpleasant" would be more apt as an oxymoron.

Comment: I suggest **neatly shambolic** due to the alternative meanings of [neat](https://www.lexico.com/definition/neat).

Comment: Given that shambolic means chaotic or disorganised I can see no problem with somebody experiencing delight in response to it; it’s not an oxymoron.

Comment: The word *delightfully* is probably used as an intensifier in those combinations, with only the suggestion of enjoyment.

Comment: There are many definitions of oxymoron. See the other questions here.

Answer (score 2):

"[Delightful](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/delightful)" is a reaction to something.

> very pleasant, attractive, or enjoyable:

"[shambolic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shambolic)" is a description of its condition.

> confused and badly organized:

Since they are not describing the same kind of thing, they can't be in direct contradiction and so are not an oxymoron.